# Using recycleview in android

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment

I read some document about using recyclingview for activity. Now i try to use recycleview to my fragment. the problem is my fragment look empty when i execute.

fragment:

```
class KategoriFragment : Fragment() {
var araclarKategori = ArrayList<AracMarka>()


private lateinit var galleryViewModel: GalleryViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    veriKaynaginiDoldur()
    galleryViewModel =
      ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)
    var root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)
    veriKaynaginiDoldur()
    var rvarackategori = root.findViewById(R.id.rvarackategori) as RecyclerView
    var MyAdapter = AracMarkaAdapter(araclarKategori)
    rvarackategori.adapter = MyAdapter

    /

    return root
}

fun veriKaynaginiDoldur(): ArrayList<AracMarka> {

    var aracLogo = arrayOf(R.drawable.opellogo, R.drawable.chevroletlogo)
    var aracismi = resources.getStringArray(R.array.arabaisim)

    for (i in 0 until min(aracismi.size, aracLogo.size)) {

        var eklenecekaracKategori = AracMarka(aracismi[i], aracLogo[i])
        araclarKategori.add(eklenecekaracKategori)
    }
    return araclarKategori

}
```

}
I create an adapter. I think there is no problem on it.
adapter:

```
class AracMarkaAdapter(tumKategori: ArrayList<AracMarka>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AracMarkaAdapter.AracMarkaViewHolder>() {

    var araclar = tumKategori

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AracMarkaViewHolder {

        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        var arackategori = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arac_kategori, parent, false)

        return AracMarkaViewHolder(arackategori)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return araclar.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AracMarkaViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.aracismi.text=araclar.get(position).aracAdi
        holder.aracLogo.setImageResource(araclar.get(position).aracLogo)

    }


    class AracMarkaViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var teksatirKategori= itemView
        var aracismi= teksatirKategori.tvaracAdi
        var aracLogo=teksatirKategori.img_arac_sembol

    }
}
```

fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvarackategori"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, when i click button, fragment opens but it is empty. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Where is `araclarKategori` initialized? I suspect that the `for` loop in `veriKaynaginiDoldur()` is not doing anything, because `araclarKategori.size` is zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After modifying the data in your list in `veriKaynaginiDoldur()`, you need to call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` so it knows to rebind the data. Or you could call `veriKaynaginiDoldur()` before you instantiate your adapter.

Edit: Your other error is in your for loop within `veriKaynaginiDoldur()`. You are making a range using the size of the `araclarKategori` list when it is still zero.

Instead of

```
for (i in 0..araclarKategori.size - 1)
```

use

```
for (i in 0 until min(aracLogo.size, aracismi.size))
```

Comment: I edited my code as your advise. But still empty. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> you have to call this veriKaynaginiDoldur() function after the below
>   lines of code below I have mentioned please check
>
> ```
>     var rvarackategori = root.findViewById(R.id.rvarackategori) as RecyclerView
>     var MyAdapter = AracMarkaAdapter(araclarKategori)
>     rvarackategori.adapter = MyAdapter
>     veriKaynaginiDoldur()
> ```

Comment: Hello Ashok, i changed code as you said. But still empty.

Comment: But you didn't bind the latest data again to adapter
in this veriKaynaginiDoldur() please bind adapter to recycler view and please try
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: Sorry i cant understand

Comment: first, you are declaring adapter object and pass empty collection as a constructor after getting data in the collection you have to set that data into the adapter

Comment: Actually i am new about android. Can you show me how to do that?